# How to initialize json file and change the values

Tags: python, json, parsing

Hi i am trying to make a Json file from which i will get data for a program that i am building.I want to make the Json file in which i would have a main key called symbol some thing like this :

```
{
   "symbol": [
      {
     "name": "LTCUSDT",
     "buy": "0.5",
     "sell": "0.5"
  },
  {
     "name": "BTCUSDT",
     "buy": "0.1",
     "sell": "0.1"
  }
 ]
}
```

and all this will e created by the information stored in lists

```
import json
pairs = ['LTCUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']
buy = [0.5 ,0.1]
sell = [0.1 ,0.1]
```

Comment: Please update the question with your code where you attempt to create a json file.

Comment: @quamrana I haven’t done that yet ,I am new with json and dont know much about it.

Comment: Ok, you need to do some more research, then write some code based on that research, and then come back here with questions (one at a time) about the specific difficulties you are having with the code and data structures / json / files etc.

Comment: @quamrana thanks I will do my research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pandas to get the inner list and then put it into a json:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
pairs = ['LTCUSDT', 'BTCUSDT']
buy = [0.5 ,0.1]
sell = [0.1 ,0.1]

df = pd.DataFrame([pairs, buy, sell], index=['name', 'buy', 'sell'])

inner_list = [v for k,v in df.to_dict().items()]

final_dict = {'symbol':inner_list}

print(json.dumps(final_dict,indent=4))
```

Comment: pandas is way overkill for the example data.

Comment: @quamrana the actual data will be huge and pandas is by far the best option